# Having trouble handling exceptions in Spring Integration

Tags: java, error-handling, rabbitmq, spring-integration

I'm new to spring integration and am confused about how to send error messages to a designated error queue. I want the error message to be a header on the original message and end up in a separate queue. I read that this can be done with a header enricher, which I tried to implement but nothing is showing up in the error queue.

Also, do I need a separate exception handling class in order for the error messages to make it to the error queue or can I just throw exceptions in my transforming methods?

Here is my xml config:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
   xmlns:int-amqp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp" 
   xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd    
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration    
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp/spring-integration-amqp.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit.xsd">

   <rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" host="bigdata-rdp" username="myuser" password="mypass" />
   <rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory" />
   <rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory" />
   <rabbit:queue name="first" auto-delete="false" durable="true" />
   <rabbit:queue name="second" auto-delete="false" durable="true" />
   <rabbit:queue name="errorQueue" auto-delete="false" durable="true" />

   <int:poller default="true" fixed-rate="100"/>

   <rabbit:fanout-exchange name="second-exchange" auto-delete="true" durable="true">
     <rabbit:bindings>
        <rabbit:binding queue="second" />
     </rabbit:bindings>
   </rabbit:fanout-exchange>

   <rabbit:fanout-exchange name="error-exchange" auto-delete="true" durable="true">
      <rabbit:bindings>
         <rabbit:binding queue="errorQueue" />
      </rabbit:bindings>
   </rabbit:fanout-exchange>

  <int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter channel="messageOutputChannel" exchange-name="second-exchange"  amqp-template="amqpTemplate" />

   <int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter channel="messageInputChannel" error-channel="errorInputChannel" queue-names="first" connection-factory="connectionFactory" concurrent-consumers="20" />

   <int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter channel="errorOutputChannel" exchange-name="error-exchange"  amqp-template="amqpTemplate" />

   <int:channel id="messageInputChannel" />
   <int:channel id="messageOutputChannel"/>
   <int:channel id="errorInputChannel"/>
```

```
<int:service-activator input-channel="errorInputChannel" output-channel= "errorOutputChannel" method = "handleError" >
   <bean class="firstAttempt.MessageErrorHandler"/>
```

```
   <int:chain input-channel="messageInputChannel" output-channel="messageOutputChannel">
     <int:header-enricher>
    <int:error-channel ref="errorInputChannel" />
       </int:header-enricher>
            <int:transformer method = "convert" >
                <bean class="firstAttempt.JsonObjectConverter" />
            </int:transformer>
        <int:service-activator method="transform">
             <bean class="firstAttempt.Transformer" />
        </int:service-activator>
     <int:object-to-string-transformer />
   </int:chain>

</beans>
```

Error Class:

```
public class ErrorHandler {
    public String errorHandle(MessageHandlingException exception) {
        return exception.getMessage();
```

QualityScorer class (called by transformer):

```
public class QualityScorer {
    private Hashtable<String, String> table;
    private final static String csvFile = "C:\\Users\\john\\Test.csv";

public QualityScorer() throws Exception {
    table = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    initializeTable();
}

private void initializeTable() throws Exception {
     BufferedReader br = null;
      String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";
   try {
       br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
               String[] data = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
            if(data.length > 6 && data[1].equals("1") && data[4].equals("0") && data[5].equals("1"))
                table.putIfAbsent(data[3], data[1]);
        }
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       throw new Exception("No file found");
  } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
        if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public float getScore(JSONObject object) throws Exception {
        float score;
        if (object == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("object");
        }
        if (!object.has("source")) {
            throw new Exception("Object does not have a source");
        }
         if (!object.has("employer")) {
            throw new Exception("Object does not have an employer");
        }
        String source = object.getString("Source");
        String employer = object.getString("employer");
            if (table.containsKey(employer) && !source.equals("packageOne")) {
               score = 1;
          } else {
                score = -1;
        }
        return score;
    }
}
```

Right now, the message being loaded has no source, so the program should be throwing the MessagingException to the MessageErrorHandler.

Transformer code:

```
public class Transformer {
 private QualityScorer qualityScorer;

 public Transformer() throws Exception {
  qualityScorer = new QualityScorer();
 }

 public JSONObject transform(JSONObject object) throws Exception {

     float score = qualityScorer.getScore(object);
     object.put("score", score);
    return object;
    }
}
```

All together, the program should receive a pre-loaded message from a queue, transform it and send it on to a second queue, which it does successfully if the source is provided in the pre-loaded message. I'm trying to handle errors and make it so they are sent to an error queue as a message header. This issue has been frustrating me for awhile, so help is greatly appreciated!

The error currently being shown in the stacktrace is:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: method <init>(Lorg/springframework/messaging/Message;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V not found
at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:96)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:89)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$1.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:129)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:114)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:44)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:92)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:358)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:269)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:186)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$1.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:129)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:114)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:44)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:92)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:358)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:269)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:186)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain.handleMessageInternal(MessageHandlerChain.java:110)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:114)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:44)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:92)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:188)
at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.access$1100(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:56)
at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.processMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:246)
at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:203)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:822)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:745)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:97)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:189)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1276)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:726)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1219)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1189)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1500(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:97)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1421)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

But nothing is going to the error queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the exception is thrown, it is wrapped together with the `requestMessage` to the `MessagingException`. Your own business exception is in the `cause` and you can get access to the `requestMessage` from the `MessagingException.failedMessage` property.

So, it looks like you have everything you need for your use-case.
Only the problem that before sending to the `error-exchange` you really should have some `<transformer>` in the error flow to properly convert that `MessagingException` to the proper message to send to the AMQP.

Comment: Hi Artem, thanks for the response! I'm still very new to this, I just updated the post with an error class and a chain to call the method in the error class, but I'm still not seeing anything show up in the error queue.

Comment: `input-channel="errorChannel" output-channel="errorChannel"` ??? That's wrong config. You make ca StackOverflow

Comment: `errorHandle(JSONObject object) `. That's wrong. You have to expect there `MessagingException`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-errorhandler

Comment: Sorry, careless copy-pasting for the output channel. Can I have it expect both MessagingException and JSONObject? I need this class to check if the object has certain properties. I added the MessagingException, but I'm now getting an error saying the ErrorHandler class has no eligible methods for handling messages. I updated the post with the full stack-trace.

Comment: That's something wrong by design. You shouldn't send normal messages to the `errorChannel`. That is exactly for the `Exception` payloads. Also consider to use custom name for the `errorChannel` property. The `errorChannel` is a global channel for any errors. Therefore you could be confused to see unexpected errors in your custom error handler.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. I updated the error class again, so that it only takes and returns MessageHandlingException and that error disappeared, but still nothing shows up on the error queue. Thanks so much for everything so far!

Comment: You should be sure that you really send `payload` compatible with the `amqpTemplate`. There is a `MessageConverter` option to consider. If you send an `Exception` as a `body`, you should serialize it with regular Java mechanism.

Comment: Would it be simpler to use the ErrorHandler interface and just override the handleError(Throwable t) method?

Comment: Does it matter if you can't send the result of the transformation to the AMQP ?

Comment: Made the errorHandle method return String instead of MessageHandlingException, so would I not need a converter now?

Comment: I put in a printline in the ErrorHandler class, and it's never executed, so I guess I'm not even getting to the errorHandle method... I'm so lost :p

Comment: You also have `outbound-channel-adapter channel="errorChannel"`. Hence, there are two subscribers to this `errorChannel` which get messages in round-robin manner. Please, start from the `Error Handling` Sample: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/errorhandling

Comment: I told you: `MessagingException` has `failedMessage` property to determine the message which has caused an error. You can extract this one and build a new message to send based on it and also use a `cause` of an exception.

Comment: Would be better do not throw `MessagingException` from your own code. The Framework does an optimization and doesn't wrap your exception to the `MessagingException` if it is already like that. Your sample demonstrate that you don't carry a `requestMessage` to the `failedMessage` property, therefore you may just lose it in your error handling process.

Comment: No reason to start a new question, when you always can edit the content of this one according our discussion and the progress in the solution.

Comment: Sorry, as you can tell I'm very new to all this. I'll post the other classes here. Should I change the argument from MessagingException to Errormessage like in the sample?

Comment: No, the `MessagingException` is enough. It is payload of the `ErrorMessage`. You need `failedMessage` to transform. You shouldn't throw any `MessagingException` from your code do not confuse Framework. Or be sure that you carry a `Message`

Comment: The message is received from the first queue as a string, then converted to a JSON Object and then the transform method is called in the service activator, so I guess I'm carrying a JSONObject instead of a message? I updated it to not throw a plain Exception instead of MessagingException in the QualityScorer.

Comment: `NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException` . Looks like you have some mix of versions in your classpath. Be sure to use compatible versions. Even would be better to poll Spring Framework dependencies transitively by Spring Integration

Comment: Ah, how can I do that? I'm using Spring Integration 4.3.10, and version 4.3.9 for the other dependencies like Spring-beans and Spring-context. I'm seeing now that version 4.3.10 for those has been released, I'll update to those and see what happens!

Comment: You don't need `<int:error-channel ref="errorInputChannel" />` because you start flow from the `<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter>` which catches all the exceptions and sends them as `ErrorMessage`s to the provided `error-channel`\

Comment: Well, versions sound very good, but your stack trace says about missed ctor in that class, therefore you are using `4.0.0` version for `spring-messaging` somehow. The fix has been done here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11345

Comment: Thanks SO MUCH!! The exception is showing up on the error queue now! Only thing left is it shows up as the payload instead of the header.

Comment: I would upvote everything but I just started on stack so I can't yet :p